# English Translation of Song "Ka Echsof"

Tags: shabbat-songs, english

I'm looking for an english translation of the Shabbat song "Ka Echsof".

The hebrew can be found on wikipedia [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A3#.D7.9E.D7.99.D7.9C.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.99.D7.95.D7.98).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artscroll has a translation: [link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/56472170/Yah-Echsof-Words).